# Function using an object created by a higher level function

Tags: r, function, object

I have two functions one inside the other

```
fun.a <- function (y,smth) { 
    z <- y*3
    sapply(smth,FUN = fun.b) 
}
fun.b <- function(x) {
    return(x+z)
}
```

If I run:

```
fun.a(2, c(1, 2, 3))
```

I get an error message because `z` does not exist in the "lower level" function `fun.b`. But I cannot pass the value `z` when using `sapply` in `fun.a`!

Maybe it exists a function allowing to create inside a function an object that exists also outside? How to solve this problem?

**Edit:** I don't want to copy paste `fun.b` inside `fun.a` and I don't want to replace `sapply` with a `for-loop`. In such a case does a solution still exists ?

Comment: `z` is within the scope of `fun.a`. You'll have to define `fun.b` with two arguments `x and y`. Or declare `fun.b` inside `fun.a`.

Comment: @ Arun. Declaring that fun.b is inside fun.a ? How do I do such a thing ?

Comment: @Arun Aahh you mean creating the function fun.b inside the function fun.a. Will it work if I do this ? Because I cannot pass two elements to fun.b from fun.a because I want to use the sapply function

Comment: I mean to cut `fun.b` and paste it after the `z <- y * 3`.

Comment: @Arun Yes it works by creating fun.b inside fun.a. But I have to say that for practial reasons it is to me not such a good solution. Isn't there a way to tell to an object that we create in a function directly exists also outside this function or in any function we call from this current function (Not sure I'm clear !!) ?

Comment: @Arun Basically let's say that I refuse to copy paste fun.b inside fun.a and I refuse to use something else than sapply to call fun.b. Is there a solution in this case ?

Comment: yes, I get your point. Maybe it's better to edit this point in your question so that people don't post that as answers.

Comment: So, you don't want to pass any other argument to `fun.b`? If so, I'm afraid there's no way to know the value of `z`.

Comment: @flodel, nice answer. I deleted the comment I wrote about using `environments`. I just dint think it's a good idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works, you use the `...` argument to pass any additional values to `fun.b`:

```
fun.a <- function (y,smth) { 
    z <- y*3
    sapply(smth,FUN = fun.b, z = z) 
}
fun.b <- function(x, z) {
    return(x+z)
}
fun.a(2, c(1, 2, 3))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are not allowed to modify `fun.b`, which I gather from the comments, then, inside the body of `fun.a`, create a copy of `fun.b` and attach an environment to it:

```
fun.a <- function (y,smth) { 
  e <- new.env()
  assign("z", y*3, envir = e)
  fun.b.copy <- fun.b
  environment(fun.b.copy) <- e
  sapply(smth,FUN = fun.b.copy)
}
```

I stil prefer @Paul's solution if you are ok modifying the way your functions take their inputs. His answer is the recommended way of programming.

Comment: I can imagine this works ok if you do not want to copy your object into `fun.b`, e.g. because the object is very large. But probably in most cases the decrease in readability of the code is not worth it. In addition, wouldn't reference classes be a good idea in this case? Than you can just pass the reference class making it obvious what the inputs are to the function, and still not copy the object.

Comment: @Paul, when you pass an object to a function, you are not making a copy of it. R uses references internally for as long as the object is not modified. So I would still recommend your approach even if `z` was big. Here I am merely answering a technical difficulty, assuming `fun.b` cannot be modified and cannot be copy-pasted into the body of `fun.a`. Otherwise I totally agree this is not a recommended programming style.

Comment: Interesting, I did not know that for objects that are not changed, R does not copy the object but remains pointing to the same memory location. Any reference for that?

Comment: I don't have a reference, but you can check it is the case using `tracemem`: `{z <- 1; print(tracemem(z)); incr <- function(z) {print(tracemem(z)); z <- z+1; print(tracemem(z)); z}; y <- incr(z); print(tracemem(y))}`. This even shows you the output of a function is not copied when assigned.